# Recommendation: Second Order Logic textbook

Tags: logic, reference-request, philosophy-of-logic, symbolic-logic

I'm looking into Universalist Realism, Nominalism, Trope theory and the application of Second Order logic to each of them, **however** I have little/no experience with Second Order logic. Please let me know any recommendations of good textbooks, preferably with exercises and answers.

(I tried Priest's introduction to Non-Classical Logic, but it doesn't touch on Second Order logic).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: [van Dalen](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&printsec=frontcover) has a chapter on SOL.

Comment: The "basic" treatise on SOL is [Shapiro](https://books.google.it/books?id=xm5eWgjpYU0C&printsec=frontcover).